# What does MonthBegin(), from Pandas, do?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to understand a code from my teacher and he uses `MonthBegin(1)` from Pandas to calculate the distance from months on a data frame.

I already tried to read the documentation but its description is too simple and there are no examples :(

The code that I'm trying to understand is:

```
month_distance = int(((df['ResearchDate'][index + 1] + MonthBegin(1)) - (df['ResearchDate'][index] + MonthBegin(1))).days / 31)
```

Comment: An aside: You teacher is using `[index]`? Seems like shift would be a lot better here to compare index 1 apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin

data = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=10, freq="8d")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["mb1"] = df[0] + MonthBegin(1)
print(df)
```

Basically it is being used so your teacher can get the difference in number of months by rounding dates to the next month's beginning.